# How can I reference an extension block to another block on magento

Tags: magento2

How can I reference the block of this catalog_product_view.xml file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="amasty_product_component"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
        <block class="Amasty\RecurringPayments\Block\Product\View\RecurringPayments"
               name="product.info.recurring.payments"
               before="product.info.addtocart"
               template="Amasty_RecurringPayments::product/view/subscriptions.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    
</body>
```

to this file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="amasty_product_component"/>
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="addToWishlistLink" xsi:type="string">.action.towishlist</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <referenceBlock name="category.product.addto">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist"
                   name="category.product.addto.wishlist" as="wishlist" before="compare"
                   template="Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/list/addto/wishlist.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>   
    </referenceContainer>
    
</body>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to have an access on the extensions php file of RecurringPayments if I can access its PHP after the block name category.product.addto.wishlist then I can add the appearance of the extensions not only from the product page but also to catalog page. Please check this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360026/how-to-add-subscriptions-extension-appearance-on-catalog-page

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the following as a child in the block where you want to place it?

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.recurring.payments" />
```

Extra info:

- In the layouts XML's there are 2 entities for placing content. Blocks and Containers.
- They are created with `<block>` and `<container>`
- One they are created, and you want to "use" a.k.a. reference those, you can do that with `<referenceBlock>` and `<referenceContainer>`. Then the only thing you need is the name of the entity. Check the XML where it is created to get the used name.

Comment: Yes I already this this, Inside of the content container                                                                    
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.recurring.payments">
<block class="Amasty\RecurringPayments\Block\Product\View\RecurringPayments"                   
 name="sample"
        template="Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/list/addto/wishlist.phtml"/>
 </referenceBlock>