# How to add subscription's extension appearance on Catalog Page?

Tags: magento2

How can I add this appearance from product page:
[image]

**to the catalog page:**

[image]

Please check also this question [Support Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360025/how-can-i-reference-an-extension-block-to-another-block-on-magento?noredirect=1#comment498953_360025) that was connected on this.